# Delete a tableadapter

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I accidentally added a table adapter to form. It's not needed and I want to delete it.

However, If I delete all references in the code to the adapter, or comment out all references,  the form bombs.

Is there any way to delete an accidentally added tableadapter?

I have tried to delete all references to the tableadapter, and/or comment them out. However, the form bombs when I try these things.

```vb
Sub InitializeComponent()

'Me.ClientsTableAdapter1 = New Proforma.ProformaDataSetTableAdapters.ClientsTableAdapter()
Me.CreditorsTableAdapter1 = New Proforma.ProformaDataSetTableAdapters.CreditorsTableAdapter()

*'ClientsTableAdapter1
*Me.ClientsTableAdapter1.ClearBeforeFill = True
 
CreditorsTableAdapter1
Me.CreditorsTableAdapter1.ClearBeforeFill = True

'Friend WithEvents ClientsTableAdapter1 As ProformaDataSetTableAdapters.ClientsTableAdapter
Friend WithEvents CreditorsTableAdapter1 As ProformaDataSetTableAdapters.CreditorsTableAdapter
```

Creditors.Resx

```xml
<metadata name="ClientsTableAdapter1.TrayLocation" type="System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
<value>213, 17</value>

</metadata>
<metadata name="CreditorsTableAdapter1.TrayLocation" type="System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
<value>378, 17</value>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the form bombs"? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: TableAdapters are designer generated code, so delete it from the designer

Comment: @MGC: never modify the designer code directly, use the designer ;-)

Comment: This is the error code I kept getting . however, the comments from Tim has fixed the problem. Thanks, - Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30456 '_clientsTableAdapter' is not a member of 'TableAdapterManager'. Proforma D:\A New Project\Proforma\ProformaDataSet.Designer.vb 9353 Active

Comment: Tim's comments fixed the problem. I found the designer and deleted it.  Resolved. Thanks, Mike